# Google autocomplete API integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am for the first time working with google APIs, I am bit clueless at this moment. I have some questions.

In last couple of days I have searched a lot about how to use google places/autocomplete API in iOS, I came across several wrappers and projects unfortunately all built 3 or 4 years ago. So they all are not useful for me because they have tons of errors and don't compile. So, here's the main problem: how can I show a tableview over my mapview with results when search bar detects text? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanking all of you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a search bar and a MapView in your UI and have the search bar autocomplete results as you type, then the easiest way to do this is to use a [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/) with a [GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_results_view_controller) from the Google Places iOS SDK.

The [add a results controller](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_results_controller) section of the documentation explains how to do this with code samples.

Comment: I've got this thing the it is more like ui/ux problem what i did to solve this problem, i created a table view on runtime with width covering my search bar and length equals to half of the screen and i just kept reloading my tableview as soon as i got my results through this i got the same experience as google maps app has.